# Spring beans life cycle dependency on transaction manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have problem with following transaction error when initializing spring bean:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

My bean seems like this:

```
<bean id="initBean" class="com.global.InitBean" init-method="execute">
```

And I use following transaction manager:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="chainedTransactionManager">
```

My execute method seems like this:

```
@Transactional
public void execute() { doSomeThing... }
```

I think that problem is when spring initializing bean *initBean* is not transaction manager ready. I tried use *depens-on* on *chainedTransactionManager*

```
<bean id="initBean" class="com.global.InitBean" init-method="execute" depends-on="chainedTransactionManager">
```

But still the same result. Is another method howto call execute method when the transaction Manager is ready?

Comment: Are you using an "initBean" instance that is created by the Spring context? Make sure that you're not creating a new instance by yourself, but get a managed instance from Spring context

Comment: Yes, it's only from spring context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `init-method` declaration from `initBean` bean definition, because Spring uses proxies to implement transactional methods, and the transactional proxy for your bean is not initialized yet when the bean is being initialized for the first time.

If the `execute` method needs to stay as the init-method of your bean, you may try to use TransactionTemplate in your method.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. But I have questions. Can I use InitializingBean and afterPropertiesSet method instead of init-method for solution? 

And my second question is it possible to initialize transactional proxy before my _initBean_ ?

Comment: I'm not sure of using afterPropertiesSet method. You can try and see for yourself. I'm sure that it's not possible to modify initialization  process of a transactional proxy, that's internal to the framework.